# EC2 User Data to fetch S3 Object

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an **EC2 instance in a Public subnet**,
The EC2 has a **S3 Full Access Role** attached to it.
I have a **.jar in a S3 folder** location.
The S3 Bucket is with default permissions, which are applied when the bucket is created.

What I want to do is implement a User Data script,
that will **download the .jar on EC2 from S3** location.
I am **able to wget the .jar only when I make the .jar Public**,

**If I do not make the .jar on the S3 Public, I am not able to wget it from the EC2**,
I do not want to make the .jar Public for security reasons.

What should I do to get the .jar from S3, without making the .jar Public?

Here's my User Data script -

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur

sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/jarName.jar

sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/nohup.out

/usr/local/bin/aws s3api get-object --bucket myDemoBucket --key folderNameDemo/jarName.jar /home/ubuntu/jarName.jar

cd /home/ubuntu/

sudo nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat jarName.jar > nohup.out &

exit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consult the documentation for a better understanding of how [EC2 Instance IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) work.

S3 and other AWS APIs are not able directly identify the instance.  Requests must still be signed. What IAM instance roles provide your instance with an easily-accessible, always fresh set of relatively short-lived, temporary credentials -- the familiar access key ID and access key secret, plus a token that must also be used in signing and submitting your request.

- with these three elements, you can generate a signed URL at runtime and pass it to wget, or
- you can fetch the file with `aws-cli`, which has built-in support for fetching and using the instance role credentials, or
- if it makes sense in your environment, you can configure the bucket policy to trust the IP address the instance will use when connecting to S3, and allow any request from that address to succeed.  This is straightforward if you are using a NAT instance or NAT gateway, or if you are using Elastic IP addresses on the instances.  It is not supported if you configure a VPC endpoint for S3.

---

Perhaps the simplest of the above choices is using the aws-cli.

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3api get-object --bucket example-bucket --key path/in/s3/to/my_object.txt /tmp/local-file-name.txt
```

Note that in scripts, it's usually a good idea to use fully-qualified paths for commands and files, since the current environment's path and working directory may not be known or as expected.  In this case, I assume the `aws` CLI executable has been installed in `/usr/local/bin/` and that you want to write the downloaded file to `/tmp/`.  Customize these as appropriate for your environment.

See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html for installlation and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html for usage of aws-cli for this application.

Comment: But I need the fetching of .jar automated, as it's on Auto scaling, how do I achieve it then? I used to fetch the .jar using User Data bash script.

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje the aws-cli is suitable for automation, and rather straightforward to use.  I've added example usage and links to the answer.  Include the command in your user-data script.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I won't need the key path bit right? As I'm using the role?

Comment: The `key` is the path and filename for the object.  From the S3 docs, [*"A key is the unique identifier for an object within a bucket. Every object in a bucket has exactly one key."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#BasicsKeys) This specifies what file you want, so, yes, you will need this.  It's not your AWS Access Key ID.

Comment: I've added a User Data script in the question with your recommendations, can you confirm if it's right, or any modifications needed?

Comment: I don't know your environment, but yes this seems like a way to do what you are asking.  You should of course verify that the command works on a running instance before trying it in user-data, since it will be much easier to troubleshoot that way.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving the file via `wget` does not pass along your identity. The content in the Amazon S3 bucket is private by default and not available to anonymous users.

You can access the bucket via an API call or by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), for example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET-NAME/FILENAME.zip .
```

The CLI is a Python app that uses the Python SDK for AWS. It knows how to retrieve credentials that are assigned to the instance as a result of it being launched with a role.

Check whether the CLI is installed on the instance. If not, install it before using it.

Comment: I've been using User Data bash script to fetch the made public .jar from S3, How I use your cli command? As I want the process to be automated?